# RxSwift: how do I work with schedulers so I run one observable at a time?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a observable “secretObservable” that I’m unable to change in any way (it’s created by a factory method). I’ve created an class Foo, which has a method foo that is called several times. In that method I want the entire observable chain to finish before the next one can start.

```
import RxSwift

// Do not touch this observable!
let secretObservable = Observable<Int>.just(5).delay(5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)


class Foo {

    private let scheduler: SerialDispatchQueueScheduler

    init() {
        self.scheduler = SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(internalSerialQueueName: "")

        self.foo()
        self.foo()
     }

     private func foo() {
        Observable<Void>.just(())
            .subscribeOn(self.scheduler)
            .do {
                print("1: \(Thread.current)")
            }
            .map { () -> Bool in
                print("2: \(Thread.current)")
                return true
            }
            .flatMap { (shouldLoad) -> Observable<Int> in
                print("3: \(Thread.current)")

                let observableThatSwitchesScheduler = secretObservable
                    .do {
                        print("4: \(Thread.current)")
                    }

                return observableThatSwitchesScheduler
            }
            .do {
                print("5: \(Thread.current)")
            }
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { (number) in

            })
    }
}
```

If I run that code above I get the following result in the console:

```
2: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
3: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
1: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
2: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
3: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
1: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
4: <NSThread: 0x600003596dc0>{number = 1, name = main}
5: <NSThread: 0x600003596dc0>{number = 1, name = main}
4: <NSThread: 0x600003596dc0>{number = 1, name = main}
5: <NSThread: 0x600003596dc0>{number = 1, name = main}
```

Does anyone know a way to change Foo.foo() (only that one and not the secretObservable) so it instead prints (1-5 and then 1-5), like this:

```
1: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
2: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
3: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
4: <NSThread: 0x600003596dc0>{number = 10, name = main}
5: <NSThread: 0x600003596dc0>{number = 10, name = main}
1: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
2: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
3: <NSThread: 0x600003abca00>{number = 10, name = (null)}
4: <NSThread: 0x600003596dc0>{number = 10, name = main}
5: <NSThread: 0x600003596dc0>{number = 10, name = main}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) By calling:

```
.do {
    print("1: \(Thread.current)")
}
```

you are going to execute the closure `onDispose` so you need to pass it to the `onNext` param to execute it as soon as the first observable emits an event. (This is the reason why you see 2, 3, 1)

2)
`concat` operator is what you need if you have to wait for one observable to complete before executing the next one so your `Foo.foo()` should be changed to return an Observable.

Try this code:

```
class Foo {

    private let scheduler: SerialDispatchQueueScheduler

    init() {
        self.scheduler = SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(internalSerialQueueName: "")
        foo().concat(foo()).subscribe()
    }

    private func foo() -> Observable<Int> {
        return Observable<Void>.just(())
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .do(onNext: {
                print("1: \(Thread.current)")
            })
            .map { () -> Bool in
                print("2: \(Thread.current)")
                return true
            }
            .flatMap { (shouldLoad) -> Observable<Int> in
                print("3: \(Thread.current)")

                let observableThatSwitchesScheduler = secretObservable
                    .do(onNext: { _ in
                        print("4: \(Thread.current)")
                    })

                return observableThatSwitchesScheduler
            }
            .do(onNext: { _ in
                print("5: \(Thread.current)")
            })
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    }
}
```